# Kohana 2: Database error where it shouldn't be

Tags: kohana

I have model 'case' and 'document'. They are in relation many to many.
In the same situation are 'customer' and 'document'.
I am using kohana 2.x

I have two methods.
In controller 'Cases':

```
public function documents($case_id) {
    $case = ORM::factory('case', $case_id);
    $documents = $case->documents;
    $this->template->view = View::factory('panel/documents/list')
        ->set('documents', $documents);
}
```

And in controller 'customers':

```
public function documents($customer_id) {
    $customer = ORM::factory('customer', $customer_id);
    $documents = $customer->documents;
    $this->template->view = View::factory('panel/documents/list')
        ->set('documents', $documents);
}
```

When I run first method everything is ok, but when I run second method, I am getting error:

```
Unknown column 'cases_documents.cas_id' in 'where clause' - SELECT `document_id` AS `id` FROM (`cases_documents`) WHERE `cases_documents`.`cas_id` = 1
```

Error is in 371 line of cms/system/libraries/drivers/Database/Mysql.php

I can't understand why Kohana invoking sql query with

```
cases_documents`.`cas_id` = 1
```

instead of

```
`cases_documents`.`case_id` = 1
```

My Case model look like this:

```
class Case_Model extends ORM {

    protected $belongs_to = array('customer', 'user', 'liquidator' => 'user');
    protected $has_many = array('users');
    protected $has_and_belongs_to_many = array('documents');
    protected $table_name = 'cases';

    public $formo_ignores = array('id', 'user_id', 'closed');

    public $formo_defaults = array(
        'liquidator_id' => array(
            'type' => 'select'
        ),
        'type' => array(
            'type' => 'select'
        ),
        'policytype' => array(
            'type' => 'select'
        ),
        'reported' => array(
            'type' => 'select'
        ),
        'sufferer' => array(
            'type' => 'select'
        ),

    );
    }
}
```

My Customer model look like this:

```
class Customer_Model extends ORM {

    protected $has_many = array('users');
    protected $has_and_belongs_to_many = array('documents', 'cases');
    protected $has_one = array('parent');
    public $formo_ignores = array('id', 'parent_id');

}
```

And Document model:

```
class Document_Model extends ORM {

    protected $has_and_belongs_to_many = array('groups', 'cases', 'customers');

    public $formo_ignores = array('id', 'name');

}
```

Please, help me what I am doing wrong or what I should to do to make this code work.

Comment: Try adding `protected $_table_names_plural = FALSE` to model.

Answer (score 0):

I already know what is wrong.

To avoid this error I only had to change inflector configuration file by adding line:

```
'case' => 'cases'
```

to get array like this:

```
$config['irregular'] = array
(
    'child' => 'children',
    'clothes' => 'clothing',
    'man' => 'men',
    'movie' => 'movies',
    'person' => 'people',
    'woman' => 'women',
    'mouse' => 'mice',
    'goose' => 'geese',
    'ox' => 'oxen',
    'leaf' => 'leaves',
    'course' => 'courses',
    'size' => 'sizes',
    'case' => 'cases'
);
```

I hope it will help someone with the same problem.